# Number of diagonal elements in the pose covariance matrix

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `control.yaml` file inside the `husky_gazebo` package defines the value of the  `pose_covariance_diagonal` parameter as  `[0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03]`.

A `pose` is made up of **7** elements - `[x, y, z,q_x, q_y, q_z, q_w]`. So, shouldn't the number of elements in the `pose_covariance_diagonal` parameter  be 7?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384087/number-of-diagonal-elements-in-the-pose-covariance-matrix/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That covariance doesn't use a quaternion for rotation portion, it uses: roll, pitch, yaw.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-08-12**:
Makes sense. Thanks!